# Python Google Drive Script to migrate Google Native Files

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-workspace

I am trying to write a script to migrate existing Google Drive shared folders & files from one Google Workspace to another. Currently, I am able to migrate the directory structure and all non-google native files using the following functions:

```py
def recursive_copy(src, dest, ignore_files=None):
    try:
        # Ignore Google Native files
        if ignore_files:
            shutil.copytree(
                src, dest, dirs_exist_ok=True, ignore=ignore_files
            )
        else:
            shutil.copytree(src, dest, dirs_exist_ok=True)

        print(f"Successfully copied {src} to {dest}!")
    except OSError as err:

        # error caused if the source was not a directory
        if err.errno == errno.ENOTDIR:
            if get_file_type(src) not in GOOGLE_FILE_TYPES:
                shutil.copy2(src, dest)
            print(f"Successfully copied {src} to {dest}!")

        else:
            print("Error: % s" % err)

def move_gdrive_directories(src, dst):

    # Make temp local directory
    dt_string = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S")
    root = os.path.expanduser("~")
    new_dir = f"{root}/Documents/temp_holder_{dt_string}/"
    if not os.path.isdir(new_dir):
        os.makedirs(new_dir)

    # Intermittent step to copy files locally
    recursive_copy(src, new_dir)
    files_list = read_all_files(new_dir)
    print(files_list)
    # Copy files from local version to destination
    recursive_copy(new_dir, src, files_list)


def copy_directory(src_dir, dest_dir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_dir):
        # Create corresponding subdirectories in the destination directory
        dest_root = os.path.join(dest_dir, os.path.relpath(root, src_dir))
        os.makedirs(dest_root, exist_ok=True)

        # Ignore files and copy only directories
        for dir_name in dirs:
            src_path = os.path.join(root, dir_name)
            dest_path = os.path.join(dest_root, dir_name)
            os.makedirs(dest_path, exist_ok=True)

            print(f"Copying directory: {src_path} -> {dest_path}")

    print("Directory copy completed.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Step 1: Copy folder structure
    source_directory = "local/path/to/GoogleDrive-source-account/Shared drives/Test/"
    destination_directory = "local/path/to/GoogleDrive-destination-account/Shared drives/Test/"
    copy_directory(source_directory, destination_directory)
    # Step 2: Copy files locally
    move_gdrive_directories(source_directory, destination_directory)
```

For the Google Native files, I have them downloaded locally and am attempting to create them in the necessary folders using the Google Drive `MediaFileUpload` function but continue to hit the following error:

```py
An error occurred: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?fields=id&alt=json&uploadType=resumable returned "Bad Request". Details: "[{'message': 'Bad Request', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'badRequest'}]">
```

Is this even a supported functionality? I am able to upload the files without defining the MimeType so I know my permissions and supporting code are correct but am hitting the error when attempting to upload the files as the designated Google native file type:

```py
def upload_to_folder():
    """Upload a file to the specified folder and prints file ID, folder ID
    Args: Id of the folder
    Returns: ID of the file uploaded
    """

    try:
        # create drive api client for destination Google Workspace
        service = authenticate()
        # Define File Meta data as Google Native
        file_metadata = {
            "name": "Test Presentation",
            "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation",
        }
        # Upload using mimetype defined by local mime.from_file function
        media = MediaFileUpload(
            "./Test Presentation.gslides",
            mimetype="application/json",
            resumable=True,
        )

        file = (
            service.files()
            .create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields="id")
            .execute()
        )
        print(f'File ID: "{file.get("id")}".')
        return file.get("id")

    except HttpError as error:
        print(f"An error occurred: {error}")
        return None
```

I am expecting to get the following response, which is what I receive when I do not define the file_meta data mimeType param:
`File ID: "1Eciif9TRmCdJbDdvVsvF0GBByPvaDF_L".`